# URL through custom field returning null

Tags: images, advanced-custom-fields

[image]I have added an image through advanced custom field. I want to retrieve image URL. I have tried with following code. It is returning null.

```
 $url = get_field('aboutus_img','aboutus');
```

aboutus_img = field name
aboutus =  field group name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer ACF link : [Link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)

And use

```
<?php echo get_field('aboutus_img'); ?>
```

Choose option image url

[image]

This example demonstrates how to display the selected image when using the Image URL return type. This return type allows us to efficiently display a basic image but prevents us from loading any extra data about the image.

```
<?php if( get_field('image') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('image_field_name'); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: But why is this get_field('aboutus_img','aboutus'); returning null

Comment: You are also wrong parameter pass in get field you check my answer some modify

Comment: @HK89 - try to use the actual parameters from the OP so that they can try it directly, without needed to modify the code.

Comment: @QStudio , idont know where the problem is , but get_field('aboutus_img') is returning null

Comment: you are set location rule in an about page in acf field , and check you are add image in field about page ,  I suggest to read acf documentation

Comment: Right, the field is stored to a specific post metadata field - so you can retrieve that on that post, using the current post ID, but on other pages you will need to pass the post ID of the post it was saved to..

Answer (score 0):

ACF provides good [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) about this function, which shows that it has the following signature:

```
get_field($selector, [$post_id], [$format_value]);
```

- $selector (string) (Required) The field name or field key.
- $post_id (mixed) (Optional) The post ID where the value is saved. Defaults to the current post.
- $format_value (bool) (Optional) Whether to apply formatting logic. Defaults to true.

You probably need to get the post ID, if you are working outside of a loop - like:

```
$url = get_field('aboutus_img', get_post_ID() );
```

Comment: No , I have tried previously with field name. It worked. but this time it Is not

Comment: Well, it's the right way to get the field data - it if exists ( has been saved to that post ) - you would need to debug $url to understand if it is empty or not..